# Extracting elements from list converted into string form in erlang

Tags: string, parsing, erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I have a group_info_db table in mnesia database.Which contain the data about group.Its attributes are groupId,Grouptype,GroupName,xxx,xxx,members.This member attribute contains name of all the members in string form(Ex-"+1@devlab,+1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,").I  fetched all the groups corresping to a member.nOW Sometimes a member is associated with many groups so a very big amount of data  is fetched from db.Like

```
  [{group_info_db,"12err1","0","Atif_aslam2","+111@devlab","+111@devlab","+1@devlab,    +1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"GroupID12","1","GroupName12","+3@devlab","+3@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+2@devlab,+3@devlab,+918800869860@devlab,+3@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"VVv","Viv_12345","0","+111@devlab","+111@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+11@devlab,+111@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"VVV5","0","Atif_aslam2","+111@devlab","+111@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"VVV6","0","Atif_aslam2","+111@devlab","+111@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"GroupID","GroupName","GroupType","+3@devlab","+3@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+2@devlab,+3@devlab,+3@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"12err","0","Viv123","+111@devlab","+111@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"12er","0","At","+111@devlab","+111@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"},
{group_info_db,"12e","0","Vi123","+111@devlab","+111@devlab",
"+1@devlab,+1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"}]
```

My problem is that i also need all the Id of group(First attribute) with which this group is associated along this Fetched data.I converted this Fetched data to string a then tried to parse it to ferch all groupids ,but that is very long method.Any other idea?

Comment: By group do you mean the strings "12err1", "VVv", "VVV5", ...? Or do you mean something else? In which format do you want them?

Comment: Groups here are like groups in whatsapp.Every group has groupid,groupname,members etc(Here each tuple is corresponding to a group .f.e-{group_info_db,"12err1","0","Atif_aslam2","+111@devlab","+111@devlab","+1@devlab,    +1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"},
is a group).There are nearly 9 groups.

Comment: @Geek if you have only 9 groups you can just stick with long method, in other case, you maybe should reconsider the way you store data.

Comment: So in this case "12err1" is the group id, or is it the group name? To be precise for your example group tell me which is the groupid, groupname and members, then I can tell you how to access it.

Comment: "12err1"(Groupid),
"0"(Grouptype),
"Atif_aslam2"(GroupName),
"+111@devlab"(Admin id),
"+111@devlab"(Creatorid),
"+1@devlab,+1111@devlab,+919470220061@devlab,+111@devlab,"(Members)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to step down the list of groups and get the second element of every group tuple:

```
get_group_id([Group|Groups]) ->
    [element(2, Group)|get_group_id(Groups)];
get_group_id([]) -> [].
```

Seeing each group tuple has the :

```
{group_info_db,GroupId,GroupType,GroupName,AdminId,CreatorId,Members}
```

you could also write the function directly using pattern matching as:

```
get_group_id([{group_info_db,GroupId,_,_,_,_,_}|Groups]) ->
    [GroupId|get_group_id(Groups)];
get_group_id([]) -> [].
```

or use the lists:map/2 function:

```
get_group_id(Groups) ->
    lists:map(fun ({group_info_db,GroupId,_,_,_,_,_}) -> GroupId end, Groups).
```

If instead of generating the members as one long string you instead generated a list of member name strings it would be much easier to work with. So that group info would become:

```
{group_info_id,"12err1","0","Atif_aslam2","+111@devlab","+111@devlab",
 ["+1@devlab","+1111@devlab","+919470220061@devlab","+111@devlab"]}
```

What type of info is it?